# How can I search for a list within a larger list disregarding the order?

Tags: python-3.x

Here's a copy of my first atempt at Tic Tac Toe. I have three weeks of experience under my belt. My code works as long as the selections are made in chronological order but if out of sequence, the winner will not be identified.
Can I have some feedback on how to find a list within a larger list regardless to the order. Also, the program doesn't seem efficient to me. Any suggestions?

```
var_board = ['1__','2__','3__','4__','5__','6__','7__','8__','9__']
x_list = []
o_list = []

def board():
    print(var_board[0] + var_board[1] + var_board[2])
    print(var_board[3] + var_board[4] + var_board[5])
    print(var_board[6] + var_board[7] + var_board[8])

##Check to see horizontal win
def horizontal():
    if(set([0,1,2]).issubset(set(x_list))):
        print("***We have a winner***")
    elif (set([3,4,5]).issubset(set(x_list))):
        print("***We have a winner***")
    elif (set([6,7,8]).issubset(set(x_list))):
        print("***We have a winner***")
    else:
        quit


##Check to see vertical win
def vertical():
    if(set([0,3,6]).issubset(set(x_list))):
        print("***We have a winner***")
    elif (set([1,4,7]).issubset(set(x_list))):
        print("***We have a winner***")
    elif (set([2,5,8]).issubset(set(x_list))):
        print("***We have a winner***")
    else:
        quit


##Check to see diagonal win
def diagonal():
    if(set([2,4,6]).issubset(set(x_list))):
        print("***We have a winner***")
    elif (set([0,4,8]).issubset(set(x_list))):
        print("***We have a winner***")
    else:
        quit

##Game play
board()

while True:
## "X" winning positions   
    position = int(input("To make your move, choose a number 1-9: "))-1
    var_board[position] = "X  "
    x_list.append(int(position))
    print("X list: ",x_list)
    board()
    horizontal()

##"O" winning positions    
    position = int(input("To make your move, choose a number 1-9: "))-1
    var_board[position] = "O  "
    o_list.append(int(position))
    print("O list: ",o_list)
    board()
    horizontal()
```

Comment: Since you're already using sets, does this version work?

Comment: Why do you have `quit` in there? You only check the x_list, you also only check horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an issue with `o_list` never being able to win? I would change your check condition to be.

```
horizontal_wins = [ set([0, 1, 2]), set([3, 4, 5]), set([6, 7, 8]) ]
def horizontal(plays):
    return any( row.issubset(plays) for row in horizontal_wins ):
```

I consider this an improvement because it accepts plays as an argument, not a global variable. That means it can work for both x_plays and o_plays.

```
horizontal(x_list) #checks if x won.
horizontal(o_list) #checks if y won.
```

Another improvement, it only creates the horizontal sets once. In this program the sets are so small it doesn't make a difference.

The final improvement, it returns the result. It doesn't print anything or decide the game, it just tells the caller the condition has been met. The reason to do this is to keep the control in the main game loop.

```
while True:
    ## "X" winning positions   
    position = int(input("To make your move, choose a number 1-9: "))-1
    var_board[position] = "X  "
    x_list.append(int(position))
    print("X list: ",x_list)
    board()
    x_wins = horizontal(x_list)
    if x_wins:
        print("x won!")
        break # end game.
    ##"O" winning positions    
    position = int(input("To make your move, choose a number 1-9: "))-1
    var_board[position] = "O  "
    o_list.append(int(position))
    print("O list: ",o_list)
    board()
    o_wins = horizontal(o_list)
    if o_wins:
        print("o wins!")
        break
```